# Is there a mind mapping software which works good in mobile and PC browser?

Tags: web-browser, mobile, web-server, mind-mapping

I am looking for a software which is creating mind maps in a browser window, I can install it on my server, but it has to be able to run both in the phone browser window and in PC as well.

I want to store my mind maps on my own server and be able to open them on PC (Linux) and on the run (Android).

I saw already many similar solutions but either they don't work on phone or I have to pay for the service, instead of installing it on my own server.

Do you know of any such product?